# Who can recommend a camera for shooting a vlog?

Tags: microphone

I am producing a vlog, and I must upgrade cameras as my current one ([Kodak PlaySport](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0030MITDK)) does not have an input for an external microphone. Something similar is all I need right now in the way of camera types.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Have you considered simply purchasing an audio recorder and syncing up the audio after the fact?  That option will likely be cheaper than buying a new camera.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, AJ! I had considered that, but I did not give it strong consideration because I know nothing audio recorders, how to shop for them or how one conducts audio syncing. Would you be able to help me with that?

Comment: there isn't really a whole lot to it.  The easiest way is to get one of those clap board things and use it at the beginning and end of your video.  Then you just line up the spike in the audio waveform with the frame where it closes.  As far as purchasing a recorder, there aren't really bad choices.  I personally use the Zoom h4n which doesn't have the best built in mics available, but allows you to plug in up to 2 microphones or other inputs.  You could also just use an audio interface like something from M-Audio and record to your computer.

Comment: If for some reason, the final clapper doesn't line up with the audio, you can adjust the duration of the audio to match correctly and it should fix timing issues unless there are dropped frames in the video.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is nothing to do with sound or sound design.

Answer (score 1):

Now, anyone in the world can give a recommendation for a specific camera. And most of them will be very wrong for your situation. If you want to see for yourself, go to Youtube and search for "camera for vlogging".

Regardless, my two cents:

- think through your requirements
- check what other people doing similar vlogs use
- buy an older model, less costly, without the very last gadgets
- if possibly, buy used / refurbished

Answer (score 0):

You would be hard pressed to go past a GoPro, you can get an external mic adapter for them, or there is a variety of 'lapel' mics available on the Internet which you can purchase. Many hundreds (if not thousands!) of Vloggers use GoPro's with great success.

They have excellent video quality for what they are.